# I need to create a function which gets an unknown number of parameters and returns their multiplication. However the result which I get is undefined

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, frontend, bind

I created an object and put the function in it, then used the *bind* method to give the function some parameters, but it is undefined in the console.

```
let numObj = {
    multyAll(...args) {
        for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (typeof args === Number) {
                arguments *= arguments[i]
                return arguments
            }
        }
    }
    }

const result = numObj.multyAll.bind(1, 2, 3)
console.log(result());
```

I tried another way around but still, I don't know why I think the function ignores ***for*** loop and returns the value of ***mul*** which I gave in the beginning

```
let numObj = {
multyAll(...args) {
    let mul = 1
    for (arg of args) {
        if (typeof arg === Number) {
            mul *= arg
        }
        return mul
    }
    console.log(mul);
}
}

const result = numObj.multyAll.bind(1, 2, 3)
console.log(result());
```

Comment: Just some problems: `typeof` returns one of a few possible strings, never the `Number` constructor. You cannot assign to `arguments` itself (at least not in strict-mode, where you should always be). `return` ends the function, but you want to first multiply all parameters, not multiply one, then return. Nothing in the task requires `Function.prototype.bind`. All in all, I'd advise to (re-?)visit a javascript tutorial, and strengthen your understanding of some concepts, as it is imho topics are easier to grasp individually, not by combining multiple, which you all do not understand yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- In the first version you use `arguments` which is a variable that gets automatically initialised with the function arguments. So to then use it for your product is not going to go well. The second version solves this point by using a different variable `mul`, which is properly initialised to 1.
- In the first version, `typeof args` is testing the wrong variable. It is not `args` you want to get the type of, but of `args[i]`. In the second version this is problem is solved.
- The `typeof` operator always returns a string, like "string", "number", "boolean", ... So that will never be equal to `Number`, which is a native function object, not a string.
- The `return` should not be inside the loop, as that will immediately stop the loop. You'll want to visit *all* arguments before returning, so that `return` must occur *after* the loop.
- `bind` takes as first argument the value that should serve as `this` during the function call. The other arguments will be the normal arguments that will be passed on during the call. So you need to insert an extra argument in the first spot, like `null`.
- You should scope your variables and not have them implicitly defined as globals. This is the case with `arg` in the second version. Insert a `let` or `const` there.
- Although the JavaScript engine will insert semicolons for you automatically, the rules for this can sometimes be tricky. It is better practice to take control over this yourself and separate your statements with semicolons.

Here is your second version (which was the better one) with the mentioned corrections:

```js
const numObj = {
    multyAll(...args) {
        let mul = 1;
        for (const arg of args) {
            if (typeof arg === "number") {
                mul *= arg;
            }
        }
        return mul;
    }
};

const result = numObj.multyAll.bind(null, 1, 2, 3);
console.log(result());
```

Finally, this task is well suited for solving with `reduce`:

```js
const numObj = {
    multyAll(...args) {
        return args.reduce((mul, arg) =>
            mul * (typeof arg === "number" ? arg : 1),
            1
        );
    }
};

const result = numObj.multyAll.bind(null, 1, 2, 3);
console.log(result());
```